# Find arc() edge while using p5js

Tags: javascript, automatic-ref-counting, distance, edge-detection

I can't understand how i can find arc() edge.
Currently i control White line with mouse.
And goal is to change that line to Red, if mouse is outside Yellow zone.

I use this code:

```
arc( xloc, yloc, size - i * steps, size - i * steps, 60, 90 );
```

[image]

Comment: From your description, it seems that this issue is related to P5js, not the browser reason, I suggest you could post your question to [p5js forum](https://discourse.processing.org/c/p5js) or the [github issues](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/bmoren/p5.collide2D) library. It is shown on the [library page](https://p5js.org/libraries/) over at p5js.org.